# FileNotFoundException when getting facebook friend bitmap - Android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, bitmap, filenotfoundexception

I'm getting an error fetching a bitmap of friends facebook profile pictures. These friends have all logged into the app. I have used examples found on StackOverFlow to create an AsyncTask and to load the bitmap, however I haven't really found another error similar/relevant to the one I have. I Have been stuck for a while now, so thanks for your time!

Calling the AysncTask:

```
        new DownloadImage().execute(new MyTaskParams(friendList.get(pos).getId(), viewHolder.friendPic));
```

MyAsyncTask:

```
private class DownloadImage extends AsyncTask<MyTaskParams, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(MyTaskParams... params) {
        MyTaskParams im = params[0];
        int id = im.id;
        ImageView imageView = im.imageView;

        try {
            URL imageURL = new URL("https://graph.facebook.com/" + id + "/picture?type=small");
            InputStream inputStream = (InputStream) imageURL.getContent(); //line with error
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);

            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        } catch(MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Logcat error:

```
07-05 13:14:57.312  15485-15529/com.dtfapp W/System.err﹕     java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://graph.facebook.com/2147483647/picture?type=small
07-05 13:14:57.312  15485-15529/com.dtfapp W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:197)
07-05 13:14:57.312  15485-15529/com.dtfapp W/System.err﹕ at java.net.URLConnection$DefaultContentHandler.getContent(URLConnection.java:1017)
07-05 13:14:57.312  15485-15529/com.dtfapp W/System.err﹕ at java.net.URLConnection.getContent(URLConnection.java:199)
07-05 13:14:57.312  15485-15529/com.dtfapp W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getContent(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:133)
07-05 13:14:57.312  15485-15529/com.dtfapp W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getContent(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:25)
07-05 13:14:57.312  15485-15529/com.dtfapp W/System.err﹕ at com.dtfapp.FriendListArrayAdapter$DownloadImage.doInBackground(FriendListArrayAdapter.java:101)
07-05 13:14:57.312  15485-15529/com.dtfapp W/System.err﹕ at com.dtfapp.FriendListArrayAdapter$DownloadImage.doInBackground(FriendListArrayAdapter.java:93)
07-05 13:14:57.312  15485-15529/com.dtfapp W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
07-05 13:14:57.312  15485-15529/com.dtfapp W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
07-05 13:14:57.312  15485-15529/com.dtfapp W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
07-05 13:14:57.312  15485-15529/com.dtfapp W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
07-05 13:14:57.312  15485-15529/com.dtfapp W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
07-05 13:14:57.322  15625-15625/? W/ResourceType﹕ ResTable_typeSpec entry count inconsistent: given 1, previously 1632
```

I have also tried using the facebook ProfilePictureView. It works using the id of the person that is logged in, but not when using the id of friends.

```
((ProfilePictureView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.profilePicture)).setProfileId(friendList.get(pos).getIdStr());
```

Comment: Put imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap); on PostExecute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using facebook android sdk [sdk](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/picture/):

```
/* make the API call */
new GraphRequest(
   AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
   "/{user-id}/picture",
   null,
   HttpMethod.GET,
   new GraphRequest.Callback() {
      public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
          /* handle the result */
      }
   }
).executeAsync();
```

In addition, when I access in the browser http://graph.facebook.com/2147483647/picture I get this message:

```
"message": "(#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: 2147483647",
```

Comment: Thank you, the second part of that really helped me!